# Adding Categories to a WordPress Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Is it possible to add categories to a Custom Post Type in WordPress?

Answer (score 7):

Put the following in your theme's `functions.php` file (changing `my-custom-post-type` to be whatever your Custom Post Type is, of course):

> `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','my-custom-post-type');`

Answer (score 0):

I found this link to be helpful with the full function call and hooks to target, it even mentions the distinction between if the custom post type was created by a plugin: http://pippinsplugins.com/add-already-registered-taxonomy/