# Display types of posts in edit.php instead of All, Published, Scheduled and Draft

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories, posts

By default, the post list (edit.php) in the admin panel displays a couple of options. It looks like this:

All (10) | Published (8) | Scheduled (1) | Draft (1)

I want to change this to display different types of posts, either by a custom taxonomy or by category. What I want it to look like is this:

Articles (5) | Releases (5) | Scheduled (1) | Draft (1)

So, the default when opening the Posts list should only include posts marked as articles, while the posts marked as releases should be in another window.

Is there any way to change this? I've been trying for a while, but can't figure it out.

Comment: What is the difference between *Articles* and *Releases*?Would it be possible to create just two different custom post types for them? This would certainly split them up.

Comment: They are both posts. However, the releases will be a lot of smaller posts that only one of the authors (it's a multi-author blog) needs to see. The reason I want them split is that I want to keep the posts list tidy. Adding all the releases would make it chaotic and impossible to find the regular articles. I have tried using a custom post type plugin, but this didn't allow me to use categories. Is there a way to create a custom post type with all the functionality of the normal post type?

Comment: Its definitely possible to have categories for custom post types. And it seems like a much easier way to go. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/adding-categories-to-a-wordpress-custom-post-type

Comment: I've gotten ahead of you and tested this already. However, these posts don't get posted at all. If I create a post and press "view", it just says the post can't be found.

Comment: Try visiting your Permalink Settings. Anyway .. it seems like we are getting somewhere else than the original question was. I suggest you create another specific question if you want to discuss this further.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just take post_formats (will be introduced with wp 3.1 in near future). These contain asides (small posts), chat, links, video, audio and so on. In general you just got a new meta-box that allows you to select the format when posting. Behind the scenes post formats are just predefined custom taxonomies bundled in a meta box. I don't know how they list, but i guess it's close to what you're searching for. Else you could switch to custom post types. Those would be listed as separate menu entries, so when you're on the post-list screen you'd only see the type of post you want to see. You could make custom capabilities that are only added to specific authors so only them could see their "own" post type. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this area for what you want seems to be very complex. These links are generated from post statuses (no taxonomies in sight) and I don't see any hooks nearby that might be useful to altering this part of template.

The one possibility would be to generate links you want (should be doable, since admin pages are ruled by [query arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) in URLs just as regular ones) and add them with JavaScript. Since this is not my area of expertise I am not too qualified to write specific JS code.

Comment: I have tried simply adding something in edit.php. It would look like this: $status_links[] = "<li><a href='edit.php?articletype=article&post_type=$post_type{$allposts}'$class>" This adds a link, which I've named "Articles", that leads to all posts taxed as articles. The only thing I can't get fixed is a way to count the posts. Whatever I try, it keeps saying (0).

Comment: @Stephan it's considered bad practice to edit core files in this way and changes will be reset on every WP updgrade so I don't really recommend that route. You are not seeing count because that is calculated by statuses as well and naturally your custom entry doesn't match any of them. You will need to add extra code to count posts.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I'm too inexperienced. I'm just trying to go by random editing things.